# Laravel & Ajax load data without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm currently working on a code that displays users activity log. Ajax will call the route and gets the response (json) results. I need to be able to display the log records on admin dashboard without refreshing the page.

**Ajax**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url:"{{ route('users.activity') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $.each(this, function(index, value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        $('#activity').append('' +
                            '<div class="sl-item">' +
                            '<div class="sl-left bg-success"> <i class="ti-user"></i></div>' +
                            '<div class="sl-right">' +
                            '<div class="font-medium">' + value.causer.username + '<span class="sl-date pull-right"> ' + value.created_at + ' </span></div>' +
                            '<div class="desc">' + value.description + '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>');
                    });
                });
            },error:function(){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: why you want to reload data? Has user new activities? filling a form? doing something? and it can be the event you are looking for  instead of click.

Comment: You can use laravel pusher. It would better for your application. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites

Comment: is data came from tabel or log file?

Comment: it's coming from a table

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send last record id in server. so you can get only new data.
my updated answer based on @stackedo answer .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastId = 0; //Set id to 0 so you will get all records on page load.
    var request = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "{{ route('users.activity') }}",
        data: { id: lastId }, //Add request data
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (index, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    lastId = value.id; //Change lastId when we get responce from ajax
                    $('#activity').append('' +
                        '<div class="sl-item">' +
                        '<div class="sl-left bg-success"> <i class="ti-user"></i></div>' +
                        '<div class="sl-right">' +
                        '<div class="font-medium">' + value.causer.username + '<span class="sl-date pull-right"> ' + value.created_at + ' </span></div>' +
                        '<div class="desc">' + value.description + '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>');

                });
            });
        }, error: function () {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    };
   setInterval(request, 1000);
});
```

In controller add were condition to query :

```
UserActivity::where('id','>',$request->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var requesting = false;
    var request = function() { 
    requesting = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:"{{ route('users.activity') }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function() {
                $.each(this, function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    $('#activity').append('' +
                        '<div class="sl-item">' +
                        '<div class="sl-left bg-success"> <i class="ti-user"></i></div>' +
                        '<div class="sl-right">' +
                        '<div class="font-medium">' + value.causer.username + '<span class="sl-date pull-right"> ' + value.created_at + ' </span></div>' +
                        '<div class="desc">' + value.description + '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                        requesting = false;
                });
            });
        },error:function(){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
   };
  if(!requesting){
      setTimeout(request, 1000);
  }
 });
```

Every seconds it does a request to your users.activity route, so there is an update every second.

Comment: you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and make sure a request is NOT already in progress before firign a new request. So you reset the `setTimeout` when request finishes. This would be better

Comment: I tried something like this before, but the issue it keeps append the same records again an again.

Comment: Another approach could be a websocket like socket.io, when the user do an activity send a message to user that can see user's activities. (docs https://socket.io/docs/).

Maybe the problem is in the queries?

Comment: the query works fine with no issues, the issue is in my ajax code only

Comment: thank you for the effort, but i still need to refresh the page